# How to add Zawgyi-One font to the font dialogue box in the Tor Browser?

Tags: help

Merry Christmas!
I would like to read Burmese websites written in Zawgyi-One font under the Tor browser.

When I went to the settings for the Tor browser, I saw the font dialogue box. But, I did not see Zawgyi-One Myanmar font in the font list. I wonder if someone can help and show me how to add Zawgyi-One font in the font list.

Thanking you in advance.

Suan

Comment: what is your OS?

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser uses a restricted set of fonts.

Since an adversary may be able to discover what fonts a user has installed, this is required to avoid fingerprinting.

**If you install this extra font you will be in a very, very small anonymity set.**

In the Tor Browser folder, there should be another folder called `Browser` and under that `fonts`. In the `fonts` folder will be the set of fonts that Tor Browser uses, adding your font file here (assuming it's in a standard format, like TTF) should allow it to be used.